# If a star forms, entropy decreases... but doesn't this require some form of energy?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy-conservation, astrophysics, entropy, stars

A cloud of matter has high entropy. In order to form a star out of matter, the entropy must decrease. For this, energy is necessary. Where does this energy come from?

Answer (score 5):

If you are just considering the (proto)star, then it comes from the work done by gravitation - i.e. gravitational potential energy is released as the (proto)star contracts. About half of this energy is used to compress the gas ($P\, dV$) and half is radiated away.

If you are considering the system as whole then the entropy increases, since the star can only get smaller by emitting lots of (thermal) radiation.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But where does the gravitational potential energy comes from?

Comment: The gravitational potential energy is contained in the original large cloud of gas that collapses into the protostar.

Comment: @probably_someone Thanks, but this does not explain the source of the gravitational potential energy.

Comment: @Julian I don't understand what you want, then. Can you give me an example of a situation where the "source" of gravitational potential energy is known?

Comment: @probably_someone To rephrase my question: Why has the original large cloud of gas high graviatational potential energy. Where does this energy come from?

Comment: @Julian It comes from the particular way that the gas was arranged in space before it collapsed (namely, from the fact that most of the particles of gas were originally located far away from each other).